# Logs full of /rest/V1/analytics/link 500 errors

Tags: rest-api, http-error-500

Working on a new M2.4 store and we've got the store blocking access to all visiting IPs except ours.

Our logs are filled all day, every day with hundreds of this error: `Error  52.73.51.61 500 GET /rest/V1/analytics/link HTTP/1.1`

The IP seems to be coming from Amazon AWS.  Any idea what this hit is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the Magento_Analytics module.

From the docs:

The Magento_Analytics module integrates your Magento instance with the Magento Business Intelligence (MBI) to use Advanced Reporting functionality. Extending Magento configuration with the module parameters: Subscription status (enabled/disabled) Industry (a business area in which the instance website works)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/mrg/ce/Analytics.html

MBI could possibly be hosted or associated with AWS